# How can I merge two integer arrays in C with for loops

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to merge two arrays but there seems to be a problem. I try to use a simple loop but it doesn't work. My first problem is that I don't know how to stop the for loop for an array, and the second is that every time it assigns some garbage value to the merged array. If someone could just give me a direction…

```c
int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,0}, arr2[] = {6,7,8,9,0};

int x = 0, merge_arr[x], i = 0, x1 = 0;

for( ; arr1[i] != 0; i++)
{
    merge_arr[i] = arr1[i];
    printf("%di ", merge_arr[i]);
}

for( ; arr2[x1] != 0; i++)
{
    merge_arr[i] = arr2[x1];
    printf(" %di ", merge_arr[i]);
    x1++;
}

for(int x2 = 0; merge_arr[x2] != '\0'; x2++)
{
    printf("%d\n", merge_arr[x2]);
}
```

Comment: `int x = 0 , merge_arr[x]` - you've just declared an array of size 0. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: Your 'merge' seems to be "concatenate `arr1` then `arr2` into result array", with the added wrinkle of "stop copying at the first zero element in the source array".  Many times, merging means "interleave the elements of the source arrays (which are in sorted order) so that the result array is also in sorted order".  That requires very different code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As C is a procedural language, it is good to define functions for such operations. C standard provides a special type `size_t` for the sizes.

```
int *concatIntArrays(int *dest, size_t maxSize, const int *arr1, const size_t arr1Size, const int *arr2, const size_t arr2Size)
{
    size_t toCopy;
    if(!dest)
    {
        dest = malloc(maxSize ? maxSize * sizeof(*dest) : (maxSize = (arr1Size + arr2Size)) * sizeof(*dest));
    }
    if(dest)
    {
        if(arr1Size <= maxSize) toCopy = arr1Size;
        else toCopy = maxSize;
        memcpy(dest, arr1, toCopy * sizeof(*dest));

        maxSize -= toCopy;

        if(arr2Size <= maxSize) toCopy = arr2Size;
        else toCopy = maxSize;
        memcpy(dest + arr1Size, arr2, toCopy * sizeof(*dest));
    }
    return dest;
}
```

or more generic one:

```
void *concatArrays(void *dest, const size_t elemSize, size_t maxSize, const void *arr1, const size_t arr1Size, const void *arr2, const size_t arr2Size)
{
    size_t toCopy;
    char *tempdest = dest;
    if(!dest)
    {
        dest = malloc(maxSize ? maxSize * elemSize : (maxSize = (arr1Size + arr2Size)) * elemSize);
    }
    if(dest)
    {
        if(arr1Size <= maxSize) toCopy = arr1Size;
        else toCopy = maxSize;
        memcpy(dest, arr1, toCopy * elemSize);

        maxSize -= toCopy;

        if(arr2Size <= maxSize) toCopy = arr2Size;
        else toCopy = maxSize;
        memcpy(tempdest + arr1Size * elemSize, arr2, toCopy * elemsize);
    }
    return dest;
}
```

where all sizes are in the elements. elemSize in bytes.

You can pass your own buffer (destination array) or NULL - then the function will allocate it for you. If the maxSize is zero it allocates as much memory as needed to accommodate both arrays.